# How to make slick slider controllable with mouse wheel?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slider, slick.js

I need to make it so that in the slick slider you can control the mouse wheel, an [example is here](https://cuberto.com/) My code: [code on codepen](https://codepen.io/Belzer/pen/gOGqwJm)

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.slider').slick({
        vertical: true,
        verticalSwiping: true,
        touchThreshold: true

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
**check this out**
```

[check this link](https://codepen.io/duy-nguyn-the-vuer/pen/QWGZNrR)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, can you please tell me how to make the page not scroll during the slide, that is, the slide should be fixed in one place